# How do I get Youtube API to autosync my captions for my video?

Tags: java, api, youtube, caption

I am trying to upload captions to my youtube video, but it's failing. Please help. Thanks.

My code:

```
{

    // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows for full read/write access to the
    // authenticated user's account and requires requests to use an SSL connection.
    List<String> scopes = Lists.newArrayList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl");
    // Authorize the request.
    Credential credential = Auth.authorize(scopes, "captions");

    youtube = new YouTube.Builder(Auth.HTTP_TRANSPORT, Auth.JSON_FACTORY, credential)
        .setApplicationName("youtube-cmdline-captions-sample").build();

    Caption captionObjectDefiningMetadata = new Caption();

    CaptionSnippet snippet = new CaptionSnippet();

    snippet.setVideoId(videoId);
    snippet.setLanguage("en");
    snippet.setName("caption");

    snippet.setIsAutoSynced(true);

    captionObjectDefiningMetadata.setSnippet(snippet);

    InputStreamContent mediaContent = new InputStreamContent(
        CAPTION_FILE_FORMAT,
        new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(captionFile)));
    mediaContent.setLength(captionFile.length());

    Insert captionInsert = youtube.captions().insert("snippet",
        captionObjectDefiningMetadata, mediaContent);

    MediaHttpUploader uploader = captionInsert.getMediaHttpUploader();

    uploader.setDirectUploadEnabled(false);

    // Upload the caption track.
    Caption uploadedCaption = captionInsert.execute();
}
```

My error:

```
GoogleJsonResponseException code: 400 : The request contains invalid metadata values, which prevent the track from being created. Confirm that the request specifies valid values for the <code>snippet.language</code>, <code>snippet.name</code>, and <code>snippet.videoId</code> properties. The <code>snippet.isDraft</code> property can also be included, but it is not required.
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "youtube.caption",
    "location" : "body.snippet",
    "locationType" : "other",
    "message" : "The request contains invalid metadata values, which prevent the track from being created. Confirm that the request specifies valid values for the <code>snippet.language</code>, <code>snippet.name</code>, and <code>snippet.videoId</code> properties. The <code>snippet.isDraft</code> property can also be included, but it is not required.",
    "reason" : "invalidMetadata"
  } ],
  "message" : "The request contains invalid metadata values, which prevent the track from being created. Confirm that the request specifies valid values for the <code>snippet.language</code>, <code>snippet.name</code>, and <code>snippet.videoId</code> properties. The <code>snippet.isDraft</code> property can also be included, but it is not required."
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:423)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
    at UploadVideo.uploadCaption(UploadVideo.java:358)
    at UploadVideo.main(UploadVideo.java:214)
```

I noticed that if I remove the setIsAutoSync line, it will upload, but it doesn't automatically sync my captions. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should not set 'isAutoSync" option, try to set 'sync' option.
It's worked for me.
Or just update the caption after it will be inserted.